# Selecting first row for group using select by expression

Tags: qgis, select-by-expression

How would/could I use the select by expression tool to select only the first row for each origin_id group?  The rows with a yellow border are the ones I want selected.

[image: example selection]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
array_first(array_agg($id,"origin_id",order_by:=$id)) = $id
```

You did not specify the sorting of your table so I assume you use the default order by feature id (`$id`). If you use another sorting, change the `order_by:=` part to a field you wish to sort by. For example to sort by `destination_id`:

```
array_first(array_agg($id,"origin_id",order_by:="destination_id")) = $id
```